# Hypen "-" is not getting accepted in SQL Parameter

Tags: .net

I have this piece of code

```
string strSQLQuery = "SELECT " + strFieldName + " FROM " + strTableName +
" WHERE " + strFieldName + " = @Value";

sqlCmd.CommandText = strSQLQuery;
sqlCmd.Connection = con;
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", strFieldValue);
resultValue = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

My strFieldValue is "IGEM - Italy"

Where as if I execute it directly without Parameter it executes

```
string strSQLQuery = "SELECT " + strFieldName + " FROM " + strTableName +
" WHERE " + strFieldName + " = '" + strFieldName  + "'";
```

Please advise

Comment: Do you get any error message? Have you tried enclosing the strFieldName with (single) quotes?

Comment: What are message are you getting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out actually in SQL database it is '-' hypen but the code which i am sending was EM Dash "-"

Answer (score 1):

What's the purpose of this code?

You appear to build your query, but you don't handle special chars in your field name, you should delimit it:

```
string strSQLQuery = 
    "SELECT [" + strFieldName + "] " +
    "FROM [" + strTableName + "] " +
    "WHERE [" + strFieldName + "] = @Value";
```

That query will work even when `strFieldName = "IGEM-Italy"`, whereas your first query will fail if the field name has the hyphen.

However this statement will always return the same thing, as you're returning the field that you're filtering by.

Your second query has:

```
" WHERE " + strFieldName + " = '" + strFieldName  + "'"
```

Which isn't the same thing - I figure it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should enclose the strFieldValue with single quotes. Furthermore, is the strFieldValue of datatype string?

Comment: If you use parameters, extra quotes should not be needed.

Comment: Actually I would think he would need brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced on .Net.

- .AddWithValue("Value", ...) without @ maybe? - SORRY SEEMS TO BE *WITH* @.
- Type conversion NVARCHARS?
- Xxx instead of Value? Value being an SQL key word or so.